# External list data to auto fill other fields in form

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have a thought in my head but I am not sure if SharePoint supports this notion. I currently don't have full access to SharePoint as yet to test my idea but please let me know if it is possible.

My goal is to auto fill a form's fields based on data input in one particular field.

To expand: I want to create an external list to my SQL Server Database. Then I would create another list which a form would be derived from that list. This form would have a field which is a lookup field from a particular column in my external list. When making a new entry within the form, the lookup field would pull the data from the external list and based on the data in the columns next to that field in the external list then it will populate the form's remaining fields. I know that may be a bit confusing but let me try to elaborate further.

If my external list has a column entitled: id,animal and the entries under it are "2" and "dog." Then in my new list it would lookup from the ID column and auto fill my remaining field with the data that is in the adjacent column in my external list.

Is this feasible?

Answer (score 1):

The following links may help you to get started:

1. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/a7af9a67-4a42-4836-9448-70ae83f5c80a/auto-fill-custom-list-form-field-based-upon-selection-in-other-field?forum=sharepointcustomizationlegacy
2. https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/anneste/2011/11/02/how-to-create-an-infopath-form-to-auto-populate-data-in-sharepoint-2010/
3. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/274d3cd1-5d81-4b69-9caf-88adb0a0e032/auto-populating-sharepoint-list-columns-based-on-value-in-one-column?forum=sharepointcustomizationlegacy

Basically, you can populate values from another list using the following:

1. Infopath forms (Link 2 above)
2. JS - SP Services (http://sympmarc.github.io/SPServices/) (Link 1 above)
3. Custom code - using C#

I have a custom solution with similar requirement and I used C# to populate values from another list based on unique key using CAML query.

Hope this helps.

Comment: suggested solution no 3 (custom code c#) is the best solution as it has no limit. You could add any type of complex data transformations today or un future.